# how to increment a counter in Argo workflow?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, argo-workflows, argo

I have written a argo dag to trigger spark job in recursion until the condition satisfies. I have a counter parameter which needs to be incremented by 1 after every successful completion of spark job. But this isnt happening. Here is the snippet of my workflow.

```
  templates:
    - name: test-dag
      dag:
        tasks:
        - name: test-spark-job
          template: test-spark-job
        - name: loop-it
          template: backfill-dag
          dependencies: [backfill-spark-job]
          when: "{{=asInt(workflow.parameters.counter)}} <= {{=asInt(workflow.parameters.batchsize)}}"
          arguments:
            parameters:
              - name: counter
                value: {{=asInt(workflow.parameters.counter)}}+1
```

Comment: value:  "{{=asInt(workflow.parameters.counter)}}+1" 

I tried this but the result was "1+1" instead of 2

Answer (score 1):

It `+1` should be part of the expression. Try:

```
arguments:
  parameters:
    - name: value
      value: "{{=asInt(workflow.parameters.counter) + 1}}"
```